# How can I get a list of external links for a Work Item using the Azure DevOps API?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a GitHub repo whose development is managed on Azure DevOps, linked using Azure Boards. In the 'Development' field of each Work Item (e.g. User Story, Task) is a list of linked GitHub commmits for that item. I would like to use the Azure DevOps API to retrieve this list for each work item.

What I've tried:

- This list doesn't seem to correspond to a field in the list of Work Item fields (from the `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/fields` [endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/fields/list)). The number of GitHub links seems to match the `System.ExternalLinkCount`, but I can't find a way to then list these links.
- Using the WIQL for `WorkItemLinks` ([documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/wiql-syntax?view=azure-devops#query-for-links-between-work-items)), but this looks like it's only for links between work items, not e.g. links from work items to other external resources
- The [general documentation covers GitHub links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/link-type-reference?view=azure-devops#github-link-types), but not in terms of the API.

Comment: Did you try `$expand` parameter in `_apis/wit/fields` endpoint?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej The documentation says *"Unless the feature flag for this parameter is enabled, extension fields are always included."* so I'd assumed this was already being included. However, I've just looked at the docstring for the corresponding function call in the Python client library (which is what I'm actually using) and can see `$expand=relations` is what I want. (So thank you! ) Though I can't see this documented anywhere on the ADO api documentation - do you know if there are details of it anywhere?

Comment: Oh wait, scratch that - I was reading the v6.0 documentation, but I think the Python client uses v5.1... or some strange beta mix of the two. In any case, 'ExtensionFields' aren't included by default, and setting the parameter to `relations` gets me what I want!

Comment: Great! Good catch with difference between version. I converted these comments into reply. Feel free to mark it as answer and upvote.

Comment: Thanks, also if you want to find a quick way to check for link between workitems and branches, i found a solution [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/948694/how-to-get-the-work-items-linked-to-a-branch-via-a.html) in the comment where it states:  
1. Get all the work items with System.ExternalLinkCount > 0  
2. filter those work items on those with a releation to vstfs:///Git  /Ref/$projectId%2F$repoId%2FGB$branchName

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use `$expand=relations` parameter to get details of linked items.

There is difference between API in v5.1 and v6.0 where on the second flog is included by default.

[image]